# How to chang the colon after figure number to another symbol?

Tags: floats, captions

I want to change the colon in the caption to another symbol e.g.

Figure 1: this is figure

to

Figure 1 | this is figure

How can I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is what I have in my preamble:

```
\usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{colquad}{:\quad}
\captionsetup{labelsep=colquad}
```

Comment: Thanks. This works. Here is code: \usepackage{caption}
\DeclareCaptionLabelSeparator{lsep}{ | }
\captionsetup{labelsep=lsep}